# Quick way to visualise multiple columns in Altair with regression lines

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, altair

So the way I have been visualising multiple columns quickly in Altair is to use `repeat`. This method is ok until I want to add regression lines using `transform_regression` or text using `mark_text` because it does not let me add layers when using `repeat`.

Pandas makes it very easy to get the correlation for a full df using `df.corr` it would be great to have some quick way to visualise all/multiple columns quickly.

Example code:

```
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data
from altair.expr import datum

iris = data.iris()

chart = alt.Chart(iris).mark_circle().encode(
    alt.X(alt.repeat("column"), type='quantitative'),
    alt.Y(alt.repeat("row"), type='quantitative'),
    color='species:N'
).properties(
    width=100,
    height=100
).repeat(
    row=['sepalLength', 'sepalWidth', 'petalLength','petalWidth'],
    column=['petalWidth','petalLength', 'sepalWidth', 'sepalLength']
)

chart
```

Here is the output from the code[image]

So my question: is there a way to quickly add any extras e.g. regression line when using `repeat`? If not what is the best route to quickly visualise multiple columns of data, in one go, while adding extras?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In place of the repeat, you can use two fold transforms and a row/column facet, and then the regression transform can be applied directly. Here is an example:

```
import altair as alt
import pandas as pd

base = alt.Chart(iris).transform_fold(
    ['sepalLength', 'sepalWidth', 'petalLength','petalWidth'],
    as_=['key_x', 'value_x']
).transform_fold(
    ['sepalLength', 'sepalWidth', 'petalLength','petalWidth'],
    as_=['key_y', 'value_y']
).encode(
    x=alt.X('value_x:Q', title=None),
    y=alt.Y('value_y:Q', title=None),
).properties(
    width=100,
    height=100
)

alt.layer(
    base.mark_circle().encode(color='species:N'),
    base.transform_regression(
        'value_x', 'value_y',
        groupby=['key_x', 'key_y', 'species']
    ).mark_line(
        color='black'
    ).encode(
        detail='species:N'
    )
).facet(
    column=alt.Column('key_x:N', title=None),
    row=alt.Row('key_y:N', sort='descending')
).resolve_scale(
    x='independent',
    y='independent'
)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I copy and pasted the above code but I'm getting one graph with all the points and lines on it, not the multiple graphs shown above.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31622208)